# MVC Criptografar/ esconder informações de acordo com a função do Utilizador

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Alguém pode ajudar a criptografar informações de acordo com a função do utilizador? Basicamente eu quero o seguinte: se a função do utilizador for = "Admin" o número de Telemóvel aparece 435267456. Se a função do Utilizador for = "User" o número do Telemóvel aparece xxxxxxxxxx.

Eu usei isto @ if (User.IsInRole ("Admin")) para esconder links dependendo da função e funciona, agora eu quero criptografar as informações mas não consigo.

**Model**

```
public partial class Cliente
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Cliente()
    {
        this.Reserva = new HashSet<Reserva>();
    }

    public int ID_Cliente { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Morada { get; set; }
    public string Telemovel { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Contribuinte { get; set; }
    public string CartaoCidadao { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataValidade { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataRegisto { get; set; }
    public string País { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Reserva> Reserva { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
  <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Telemóvel</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                <input name="Telemovel" class="form-control" type="text" value="@Model.Telemovel" readonly="readonly">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controlador**

```
// GET: Clientes/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{


    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Cliente cliente = db.Cliente.Find(id);
    if (cliente == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    ViewBag.ListaReservas = db.Reserva.Include(p=> p.Cliente).Where(p => p.ID_Cliente == cliente.ID_Cliente);


    return View(cliente);
}
```

Comment: É apenas para visualização ou você fará algo com essa informação?

Comment: @Barbetta  É apenas para visualização

Comment: Você quer criptografar ou simplesmente ocultar a informação? O titulo não tem nada haver com o que é dado como exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é apenas visualização não há necessidade de fazer algo complexo, você pode na sua `view` fazer um `if` e exibir ou não os dados:

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Telemóvel</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
                @if (User.IsInRole ("Admin"))
                {
                    <input name="Telemovel" class="form-control" type="text" value="@Model.Telemovel" readonly="readonly">
                }else
                {
                    <input name="Telemovel" class="form-control" type="text" value="xxxxxxxxxx" readonly="readonly">
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Outra opção seria **não** usar esse `if` na `view` e no seu `controller` mudar a informação para o que deseja de acordo com a permissão:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Cliente cliente = db.Cliente.Find(id);
    if (cliente == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    if(!User.IsInRole ("Admin"))
    {
        cliente.Telemovel = new String('x', cliente.Telemovel.Length);
    }

    ViewBag.ListaReservas = db.Reserva.Include(p=> p.Cliente).Where(p => p.ID_Cliente == cliente.ID_Cliente);


    return View(cliente);
}
```

Note que na segunda opção no `if` caso ele não seja **admin** ele atribui a propriedade `Telemovel` o valor **xxxx**, nesse caso a quantidade de "x" respeita o tamanho da `string`

Comment: Perfeito, resultou na perfeição!! Muito obrigado !!!!

Comment: @Heftysilva Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos. ;)

Answer (score 0):

A forma correta seria voce implementar uma classe de domínio (não diretamente na View usando Razor), o Model neste caso, que faz a validação e retorna apenas as informações permitidas baseadas no nível de permissão do usuário.

Para isso seria correto criar uma view da tabela usuário para cada tipo de usuário, exemplo:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_userForAdmin AS
 SELECT name, mobile // E todas as outras permitidas aos admins
 FROM [User];
```

Em Model.Usuario (que voce não postou o código) deve existir um método "getUserInfos(int user_id, string permission_role)" que fará a query na VIEW apropriada e não mais direto na tabela.

Exemplo:

```
getUserInfos(int user_id, stirng permission_role){
  switch(permission_role){
    case PERMISSIONS.ADMIN:
     // SELECT na VIEW e não mais na tabela User
  }
}
```

Referencias:
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application